# C# multiple inheritance with interfaces and memory leaks

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# program where I have a class that inherits multiple interfaces like following

```
 class MyClass:IMyInterface,IExampleInterface,IDisposable
 {
 }
```

But as such neither IMyInterface or nor IExampleInterface inherits IDisposable individually. But  when I create an instance of an interface for example

```
  IMyInterfacce myInterface = new MyClass();
```

and analyze my code (using Coverity tool) I find that there is a resource leak and the object myInterface is not releasing the resources held by it in the memory.
Though I'm instantiating MyClass instance using new MyClass() but as such IMyInterface doesn't implement IDisposable though MyClass does.

Then why on the earth I'm getting a complain about resource leak/memory leak as far as "myInterface" object is concerned.

Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: `IMyInterface` is just an interface, it doesn't have an implementation, its basically a code-contract, so it can't hold memory. Whatever is in your implementation is doing it.

Comment: If any interfaces of `MyClass` has impl `IDisposable`, why you try impl it in MyClass? And if `IMyInterfacce` is not impl `IDisposable`, but you use `IMyInterfacce myInterface = new MyClass();`, you cannot dispose your object, you need to use type conversion.

Comment: @Ron you are absolutely right that IMyInterface doesn't have an implementation so can't hold memory. But when I instantiate IMyInterface myInterface = new MyClass(); That's when myInterface occupies space in memory and it's not releasing it after the code goes out of scope.

Comment: @user2913184 `IDisposable` doesn't release resources automatically, it only releases them when you explicitly call `Dispose` or use it in a `using` statement, which calls `Dispose`.

Comment: And I was like how come impl IDisposable on MyClass makes a case for the disposal of myInterface object when I instantiate IMyInterface.

Comment: @user2913184 you are instantiated a `MyClass` object, not a `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Yeah I edited my question above and changes it to MyClass.

Comment: *"That's when myInterface occupies space in memory and it's not releasing it after the code goes out of scope"* No, its still `MyClass` in memory, but you interact with it with the `IMyInterface` code contract. `IMyInterface` can't be instantiated, so it can't be a type in memory, nor can any operations run inside of its context, they are in the `MyClass` context. `IMyInterface` can *inherit* `IDisposable` but it can't implement it... `MyClass` has to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a class and assign it to an interface, you've still created an instance of the class type.

```
IMyInterfacce myInterface = new MyClass();
```

Still creates a `MyClass` object and myInterface references a `MyClass` object.  So the `myInterface` still references an instance of a class that needs to be disposed.

You'll have to cast it back and call `Dispose` on it when you are done:

```
((IDisposable)myInterface).Dispose();
// Or
((MyClass)myInterface).Dispose();
```

Or you could wrap this in a using statement:

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass()) {
    MyInterface myInterface = myClass;
}
```

Comment: @shf301I guess this is absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks a ton buddy.

Comment: @user2913184 if you found this helpful mark the quesiton as answered.